# Convergent Finite Difference Scheme for Parabolic Equation

Tags: finite-difference, convergence, stability, parabolic-pde

Consider the PDE $$u_t = b_{11}u_{xx} + 2b_{12}u_{xy} + b_{22}u_{yy},$$
where $b_{11}, b_{22} > 0$, and $b_{12}^2 < b_1b_2$.
In Strikwerda's book, the ADI scehme \begin{align*}
\left( 1 - \frac{k}{2}  b_{11} \delta_x^2\right)v^{n+1/2} &= \left( 1 + \frac{k}{2}  b_{22} \delta_y^2\right)v^{n} + kb_{12} \delta_{0x} \delta_{0y} v^n \\
\left( 1 - \frac{k}{2}  b_{22} \delta_x^2\right)v^{n+1} &= \left( 1 + \frac{k}{2}  b_{11} \delta_x^2\right)v^{n+1/2} + kb_{12} \delta_{0x} \delta_{0y} v^{n+1/2} \\
\end{align*} 
is stated to be convergent. I was able to show that it was consistent, but I am struggling with stability. Making the substitution $v^{n} = g^n e^{il \theta}e^{i m \phi}$, and $v^{n+1/2} = \tilde{g}g^n e^{il \theta}e^{i m \phi}$,
\begin{align*}
\left(1 + 2\mu b_{11} \sin^2{ (\theta/2 
)} \right) \tilde{g} &= \left(1 - \mu( 2b_{22} \sin^2{ (\theta/2 
)} + b_{12}\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}) \right) \\
\left(1 + 2\mu b_{22} \sin^2{ (\theta/2 
)} \right) g &= \left(1 - \mu( 2b_{11} \sin^2{ (\phi/2 
)} + b_{12}\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}) \right)\tilde{g}, \\
\end{align*}
where $\mu = \frac{k}{h^2}$. This implies that $$g = \frac{\left(1 - \mu( 2b_{11} \sin^2{ (\theta/2 
)} + b_{12}\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}) \right)\left(1 - \mu( 2b_{22} \sin^2{ (\phi/2 
)} + b_{12}\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}) \right)}{\left(1 + 2\mu b_{11} \sin^2{ (\theta/2 
)} \right)\left(1 + 2\mu b_{22} \sin^2{ (\phi/2 
)} \right)}$$
Ultimately, I want to find some restriction on $\mu$ such that $\left| g \right| \leq 1 $. Since most ADI schemes are unconditionally stable, I expect that this fraction is automatically bounded above by $1$, but I'm not sure how to show that. Any help would be much appreciated.